# JQuery DataTables - show "loading" message while exporting huge number of rows

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable I am using to load my data. However I am struggling to export huge number of rows ex 15-20k rows.

```
$('#example').DataTable( 
    {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
           'excel'
        ],
        initComplete: function(){
            $('.buttons-excel').style('display', 'none')
            $('#custom-excel-button').click(function(){
                $('.buttons-excel').trigger('click')
            })
        }
});
```

I have a custom button `<button id='custom-exel-button' />`

When user clicks on this button I want to trigger export functionality It works fine but I am having some UI issues. When its a huge volume, it just hangs on the button.

Instead I want to show some sort of loading icon when an export is happening.

Is there a callback I can use to know when export is completed? So I can just load a loader icon when user clicks the button then hide the loader on the callback.

Comment: I think that your first issue is thinking you should be doing anything in the UI with 15-20k rows of data. No person can even begin to consume that amount of information. Why make the browser produce an export for that? You had to get the data from somewhere, most likely a server. Why not have your button tell the server, you know the big computer that's more suited to working with large data sets, to produce the export and then the client can just download it?

Comment: Do it on the server....

Comment: As much as I want to do this on server and do it paginated way, but our current infra is pretty huge, and the data we're consuming on datatable is coming from complex sources. It would require heavy lifting in the infra side. Is there a way to do this via browser? Just show a loading icon when those records are being processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [button action](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action) to do this.

In the example below, I am using the [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) library, just for convenience in this basic demo.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.15.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

The button code in the DataTable:

```
buttons: [
  { 
    text: 'Excel',
    action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
      var that = this;
      Swal.fire('Data is being loaded...');
      setTimeout(function() { 
        $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(that, e, dt, node, config);
        Swal.close();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
]
```

The `excelHtml5.action.call()` function is how I manually trigger the Excel file creation in this case, instead of the more usual appraoch.

*(Having said that, I completely agree with the comments in the question: This is a job which should really be performed on the server. I don't see any reason to show this much data to the user in a web page, even prior to the Excel export. I imagine the browser and DataTables take quite some time to process/display the raw data, also.)*